# How do I run bootchart on Fedora 23

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, systemd

My computer takes a long time to boot, and I want to analyze the boot process using `bootchart`.

On Ubuntu, `bootchart` is provided as a package that installs a command-line tool. That package is not present in Fedora -- [this guide from the Fedora Project](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bootchart) states that I should add `init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart` at the end of the *kernel* line in the bootloader configuration file.

The file `usr/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart` is present on my system, but I don't know how do I proceed in order to activate it upon boot.

I'm using grub as the bootloader, (not sure if it's grub or grub2). My configuration file is in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. There's no *kernel*  line in it, or any entry with `init=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Making Temporary Changes to a GRUB 2 Menu](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Making_Temporary_Changes_to_a_GRUB_2_Menu.html) from the Fedora System Administrators' Guide.* It says:

> 1. Start the system and, on the GRUB 2 boot screen, move the cursor to the menu entry you want to edit, and press the e key for edit.
> 2. Move the cursor down to find the kernel command line. The kernel command line starts with **linux** on 64-Bit IBM Power Series, **linux16** on x86-64 BIOS-based systems, or **linuxefi** on UEFI systems.
> 3. Move the cursor to the end of the line.
> 4. Press `Ctrl+a` and `Ctrl+e` to jump to the start and end of the line, respectively. On some systems, `Home` and `End` might also work.
> 5. Edit the kernel parameters as required.

In this case, you want to add the `init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart` parameter.

Then, press `Ctrl-x` to boot.

A temporary change seems what you probably want for bootchart. If you want to make the change permanent, see [Making Persistent Changes to a GRUB 2 Menu Using the grubby Tool](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Making_Persistent_Changes_to_a_GRUB_2_Menu_Using_the_grubby_Tool.html).

---

PS: On Fedora 23, you're using GRUB 2.

---

<sub>* CC-BY-SA 3.0,  Copyright © 2015 Red Hat, Inc. and others.</sub>