# Startup benchmarking on Fedora 24

Tags: linux, boot, performance, fedora, benchmarking

My Fedora 24 PC is taking more than 2 minutes to reach a usable state.

Back when I used Ubuntu, [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) would generate a detailed graph of boot time showing how long each component took to initialize. There is a [bootchart package for Ubuntu](https://pkgs.org/ubuntu-16.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/bootchart_0.90.2-8ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html) and, upon installed, it can be invoke via CLI as `bootchart`.

Although there is no `bootchart` package for Fedora, I found a quite convoluted way ok [invoking bootchart](https://superuser.com/questions/1107198/how-do-i-run-bootchart-on-fedora-23). However, it didn't provide much in a way of an insight on improving boot speed:

[image]

How can I obtain a more in-depth report on what makes Fedora boot so slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out `systemd-analyze` provides detailed information

> systemd-analyze - Analyze system boot-up performance. (...) Determine system boot-up performance statistics and other state and tracing information

It comes preinstalled in Fedora an can be invoked simply by calling

- `systemd-analyze blame`: shows how long it took for each service to start.

  > prints a list of all running units, ordered by the time they took to initialize. **Note that the output might be misleading as the initialization of one service might be slow simply because it waits for the initialization of another service to complete.**
- `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

  > prints a tree of the time-critical chain of units. **Note that the output might be misleading as the initialization of one service might depend on socket activation and because of the parallel execution of units.**